# raspbian MIDI connection script at autostart

Tags: raspbian, midi

I try to use raspberry together with USB MIDI keyboard and qsynth.

I use the following script at autostart that starts qsynth and connects MIDI keyboard to qsynth.

```
#!/bin/sh
qsynth -a=alsa &
sleep 5
aconnect 20:0 128:0
echo "Done"
```

The autostart procedure is taken from [http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-autostart-apps-in-rasbian-lxde-desktop]

It doesn't work. Manual run of the script works correctly. After reboot when I connect with VNC I see that qsynth is working but connection to MIDI keyboard is not established.

Is seems like there is a problem with USB initialization at the startup, may be I use wrong order of startup.

Comment: The USB subsystem in general will be up and available by the time userspace applications start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During startup, many other programs are being run, so it's likely that `qsynth` takes longer than five seconds to start.

Wait until `aconnect` succeeds:

```
#!/bin/sh
qsynth -a=alsa &
while ! aconnect 20:0 128:0; do sleep 1; done
echo Done
```